# Knapsack algorithm, How to get better performance?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, c++11, openmp

Openmp outperforms the serial code by factor x2, but I would like to have a better performance if it is possible.

Here is the serial code in c++:

```
for (int k = 0; k < numelem[i]; k++)
{
    sumK = sumK - weight[k];
    int cmax = 0;
    cmax = max(capacity - sumK, weight[k]);

    for (int c = capacity; c >= cmax; c--)
    {
        if (f[c] < f[c - weight[k]] + value[k])
        {
            f[c] = f[c - weight[k]] + value[k];
            M[capacity * k + c] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

For the openmp version, I use two f0,f1 arrays which are swapped at each iteration. This helps me to prevent the race condition, but I suppose that false sharing is still present (not sure). Other my supposition is that, the conditional statements inside pragma for slow down the execution.

```
        for (int k = 0; k < numelem[i]; k++) {

            sumK = sumK - weight[k];
            int cmax = 0;
            cmax = max(capacity - sumK, weight[k]);
            int c = capacity;

            if (k % 2 == 0) {

#pragma omp parallel
    {

#pragma omp for
                for (c = capacity; c >= cmax; c--) {

                    //FALSE SHARING???

                    if (f0[c] < f0[c - weight[k]] + value[k]) {
                        f1[c] = f0[c - weight[k]] + value[k];
                        M[capacity * k + c] = 1;
                    } else {
                        f1[c] = f0[c];
                    }
                }
            } 

            else {

#pragma omp for
                for (c = capacity; c >= cmax; c--) {

                    //FALSE SHARING???

                    if (f1[c] < f1[c - weight[k]] + value[k]) {
                        f0[c] = f1[c - weight[k]] + value[k];
                        M[capacity * k + c] = 1;
                    } else {
                        f0[c] = f1[c];
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    }
```

Here you can find the full code for [serial c++](https://github.com/nico-mkhatvari/OpenCL/tree/master/Knapsack%20C%2B%2B) and [openmp c++](https://github.com/nico-mkhatvari/OpenCL/tree/master/Knapsack%20OpenMP/src)

***This work is based on this article***:

- [Solving knapsack problems on GPU by V. Boyera, D. El Baza,  M. Elkihel](https://cel.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01152223/document)
- related work: [Accelerating the knapsack problem on GPUs by Bharath Suri](http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:439054/FULLTEXT01.pdf)

Comment: What is f[]?  What is M[]?  Explain the recurrence that your code implements.

Comment: M - is the decision matrix, which contains the decision made at each iteration. f is the array that is used to compute whether an element should be part of the knapsack.

Comment: You may want to try [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) seeing as you already have working code.

Comment: I mean what, specifically, does f[i] hold?  What does M[i] hold?  In the meantime: Unless it's a specific optimisation for GPUs, it strikes me as wasteful to store just a single bit of information in each entry of M[] -- if you're using one of the usual recurrences then you don't need to store this information anyway, since it can be determined from the values in f[] in O(1) time.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I have no idea what the algorithm is or is supposed to do.

I would keep the code simple and totally avoid the false sharing by using local variables (if possible).

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    // I'm using auto, correct the type and initialize as needed
    auto f_local = f;
    auto sumK_local = sumK;

    for (int k = 0; k < numelem[i]; k++)
    {

      sumK_local = sumK_local - weight[k];
      int cmax = 0;
      cmax = max(capacity - sumK, weight[k]);
#pragma omp for
      for (int c = capacity; c >= cmax; c--)
      {
          if (f_local[c] < f_local[c - weight[k]] + value[k])
          {
            f_local[c] = f_local[c - weight[k]] + value[k];
            M[capacity * k + c] = 1;
          }
      }
    }
#pragma omp critical
    {
        for (int c = capacity; c >= cmax; c--)
        {
            if (f[c] < f_local[c])
            {
              f[c] = f_local[c];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Edit: I have moved pragma omp parallel to the correct position. Accordingly to my last edit, if I use your solution I would lose the the local array...

Comment: Why not place the pragma outside of the `k` loop? The whole point is to create a local copy and copy it back in the critical section?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what the pragma instructions are for, but regarding the algorithm, you could optimize this part:

```
for (c = capacity; c >= cmax; c--) {
```

Where I'm guessing `capacity` represents the entire capacity of your knapsack.

The idea is that you don't always need to iterate down starting from this. It's enough to iterate starting from the sum of weights of the items you have currently visited.

So you can do something like this:

```
      currentCapacity = 0;
      for (int k = 0; k < numelem[i]; k++) {

            currentCapacity += weight[k];
            sumK = sumK - weight[k];
            int cmax = 0;
            cmax = max(currentCapacity - sumK, weight[k]);
            int c = currentCapacity;

            if (k % 2 == 0) {

#pragma omp parallel
    {

#pragma omp for
                for (c = currentCapacity; c >= cmax; c--) {
```

It won't affect the big-oh complexity, but it should offer a performance boost in practice, especially if you have large capacities.

After this, you should also force the current capacity to never exceed your knapsack's capacity:

```
currentCapacity = min(currentCapacity, capacity);
```

After the `+=` I've added.